# postgresql condition value as a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

given the following query in postgresql

```sql
select name
from foo
where id = (
  select id
  from bar
  where tag @> '[{"Value":"val"}]'
)
and (
  attrs @> '[{"Key": "baz", "Value": "false"}]' -- baz column
  or
  attrs @> '[{"Key": "spam", "Value": "false"}]' -- spam column
  or
  jsonb_array_length(vals) = 1 -- length column
)
```

how the query needs to be changed to return a `baz`, `spam` and `length` columns which have the value either `true` or `false` if the corresponding condition is met?

for instance, if `jsonb_array_length(vals) = 1` then there will be corresponding column named `length` that has the value `true` or `false` otherwise.

Comment: A logical expression is allowed in SELECT list and returns exactly true/false

Comment: @Serg can you please share a concrete example for my use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A logical expression is allowed in SELECT list and returns exactly true/false

```
select name, 
   attrs @> '[{"Key": "baz", "Value": "false"}]'  baz,
   attrs @> '[{"Key": "spam", "Value": "false"}]' spam,
   jsonb_array_length(vals) = 1 len
from foo
where id = (
  select id
  from bar
  where tag @> '[{"Value":"val"}]'
)
and (
  attrs @> '[{"Key": "baz", "Value": "false"}]' 
  or
  attrs @> '[{"Key": "spam", "Value": "false"}]' 
  or
  jsonb_array_length(vals) = 1 
)
```

Using LATERAL to dedup the code:

```
select name, 
   t.baz,
   t.spam,
   t.len
from foo
cross join lateral (
   select attrs @> '[{"Key": "baz", "Value": "false"}]'  baz,
   attrs @> '[{"Key": "spam", "Value": "false"}]' spam,
   jsonb_array_length(vals) = 1 len
) t
where id = (
  select id
  from bar
  where tag @> '[{"Value":"val"}]'
)
and (
  t.baz 
  or
  t.spam 
  or
  t.len 
)
```

You may wish to check execution plan before implementing it in production

Comment: is there a way to not duplicate the condition lines?

Comment: Yes you can add a lateral join to compute an expression and use it both in select and where. It can though have a bad impact on execution plan.